# Html5 player customization

Tags: html, audio, media

I am trying to customize audio player. I got a control under buttons PAUSE,PLAY and VOLUME, now can apply different styles. Here is my code

```
 <audio controls id=aud>
   <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <button class='btn btn-default' onclick="document.getElementById('aud').play()">Play</button> 
  <button class='btn btn-default' onclick="document.getElementById('aud').pause()">Pause</button> 
  <button class='btn btn-default' onclick="document.getElementById('aud').volume += 0.1">Vol+ </button> 
  <button class='btn btn-default' onclick="document.getElementById('aud').volume -= 0.1">Vol- </button> 
  <input type="range" class='btn btn-default' onclick="document.getElementById('aud').seekable()"></input>
```

Now i have a problem how to customize progress bar of the player.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a `onloadedmetadata` for your audio tag to get total duration `duration` and update the min and max range in your input sleek bar.

```
aud.onloadedmetadata = function(){
 audioRange.max = aud.duration;
 console.log('Current audio duration: ',aud.duration);
}
aud.ontimeupdate = function(){
    audioRange.value = aud.currentTime
}
audioRange.onclick = function(e){
    aud.currentTime = audioRange.value
}
```

Online [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sasivarunan/fqv32dxz/)

Comment: can you write this pice of code please, because I do not imagine how to write this part, and can not find tutorial

Comment: @Pavel If this what you're looking for you can accept my answer :)